# Visual Studio 2008 (C++) additional directories for debugging?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, visual-c++, path

In prior versions of Visual Studio one could specify paths for DLL files when debugging an application. I do not see a way to do this in version (2008). Is this due to the move toward deployment of applications with all DLL files, etc. in the application's directory(ies)?

Am I missing something, or is there no way to do this?

---

It was in [Visual C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_C%2B%2B#32-bit_versions) 6. I think it was menu *Tools* -> *Options* -> *Directories* -> executable files.

Perhaps now this was not what I thought it was - this may be the same as what I have found in Visual Studio 2008.

Basically I am looking for a way to "append" to the PATH environment variable - just for running the EXE file project open in Visual Studio (without actually editing the path environment variable).

The workaround is for me to copy all the dependencies to the working directory. That will work - it just involves some changes to other projects - and gathering third-party stuff (this was a huge migration from Visual C++ 6).

Comment: Where was this option in 2005? Might help to specify some additional detail like that so we know what setting you actually mean. Thanks.

Comment: Yep - you're right - see edit

Answer (score 1):

It doens't work that way anymore (since VS 6.0). Today, once a DLL file is loaded by the process, the DLL file gets a notification and search for the DLL debug symbols.

First it looks inside the DLL file (the DLL can keep the path for the debug symbols). If not, it searches the symbol path (menu *Tool* -> *Options* -> *Debugging* -> *Symbols*) then it looks inside the window directory.

It tries to load the debug symbol only if needed (to resolve a breakpoint for example) or if you manually ask the symbols to be loaded (in the case if the symbols were not found, it will prompt you for them).

You can see where the debugger have tried to look for the symbols by openning the modules pane (menu *Debug* -> *Window* -> *Modules*) right clicking on the module and selecting *show debug information* (it doesn't have Visual Studio here, so it might be called by a different name).

Thanks God(s) that we no longer need to configure the path for each DLL file.

Answer (score 0):

Use menu *Tools* -> *Options* -> *Project and Solutions, where you can specify all the search paths for your project.

Comment: Yeah - i saw that one before.  Looked promising the comment is that it is for exes to look for when BUILDING a project - not for looking for DLLs when debugging.  I'm guessing

Comment: There are a couple of options in the drop down, one is called "executable file".

This is what it says:

Executable files.

Path to use when searching for executable files while building a VC++ project.  Corresponds to environment variable PATH.