# C++ header file includes <> paths

Tags: c++, visual-studio, header-files, visual-c++-6

Quick background.  I'm using the following:

1. Windows XP
2. Visual Studio 6.0

When you specify a #include like the following where does it look for this header file:

```
#include <msxml.h>
```

Is it looking at an environment variable to determine which paths to look at?  If so which one?

Comment: Visual Studio **6**? I had to ask google to know how ancient exactly that version is (it was released 1998, for the record). Why the use an IDE from the last century? Grap a more recent Express version or any open source IDE. Even the widely cursed Dev-C++ would be modern compared to this...

Comment: @delnan: lots of people are stuck working on legacy projects where it is not practical to upgrade.

Comment: @delnan You wouldn't be asking that question if you've ever tried to upgrade a large scale project written in visual studio 6.0 to 2010.

Comment: Been where you are.  VC 6 is end-of-life'd.  If anything every goes wrong with it, you're completely screwed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the IDE, it sets the various search paths through GUI options in in Tools->Options->Directories.

(See also [Visual Studio 2008 (C++) additional directories for debugging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719896/visual-studio-2008-c-additional-directories-for-debugging).)

Answer (score 0):

The environment variable is called, easily enough, `INCLUDE`. You can also manually specify additional include directories with `-I/path/to/include`.

And as a side note, it's 2011. 1996 passed a looong time ago..